# How would one unit test api call method (rxjava+retrofit)?

Tags: unit-testing, retrofit2, rx-android

I'm trying to unit test an api call made with retrofit and rxjava.
In order to do that i'm mocking the api call object but api calls subscriber won't trigger its onNext method.

ApiCallsTest.java:

//custom object replacing api call response object

```
Observable<FastRechargeClass[]> apiObservable = Observable.just(fastRechargeList);
InterfaceAPI api = mock(InterfaceAPI.class);
when(retrofitApi.getApiInterface(context)).thenReturn(api);        when(api.getLatestTransactions("token")).thenReturn(apiObservable);
apiCalls.getLatestTransactions("token",context);
```

ApiCalls.java:

```
public void getLatestTransactions(String token, final Context context) {
        String methodName = "getLatestTransactions";

        InterfaceAPI api = retrofitApi.getApiInterface(context);
        Observable<FastRechargeClass[]> call = api.getLatestTransactions(token);
        call.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Observer<FastRechargeClass[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                WriteLog.print("onSubscribe");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(FastRechargeClass[] fastRechargeClasses) {
                fastRechargeManager.runUpdateFastRechargeDb(fastRechargeClasses);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                logOnFailureRequests(methodName, e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
            }
        });
    }
```

[When running test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58XOx.png)

[onSubscribe is being called and it stops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcxgQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to trigger event emission manually. To do this you need to call method

`.blockingFirst()` 
or 
`.blockingGet()`

depends of observable type you are using.
So you have to add

```
call.blockingGet()
```

at the end of getLatestTransactions method or this method should return created observable and call blocking get inside a test method.

Comment: Your comment was very useful, in order to make observer call onNext i had to change call.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Observer<FastRechargeClass[]>() {...} to         call.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Observer<FastRechargeClass[]>() {...}. I guess it was related to threads managing.

Comment: @PanduruIonut Right ;)